# iOS UITableView cell's custom separator doesn't change its width on landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have my UITableView and have set my cell's separator. Everything seems fine, but my separator doesn't change its width on landscape. Here is how it looks:
[image]

Here is the code where I create my custom cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil){
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ListCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
    }
   //set cell's image and texts
   ... 


    UIView *separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 1)];
    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0 saturation:0 brightness:0 alpha:0.1];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    return cell;
}
```

Any ideas, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You haven't told the view, in any way, how to resize...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add separator line property in ListCell.h-

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)  UIView *separatorLineView;
```

Try to replace separator line's code with following code -

```
int screenHeight;
if ( [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
    &&  [[UIApplication sharedApplication ]statusBarOrientation] != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
    screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.width;
} else {

    screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.height;
}

if(cell.separatorLineView.superview == NULL){
     cell.separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenHeight, 1)];
    cell.separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0 saturation:0 brightness:0 alpha:0.1];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.separatorLineView];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

I will definitely work!

Or you can add separator line by storyboard-

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked! One more problem occurred - is it possible that when I scroll through the table, cell's separator is being drawn every time over and over on the same line? Every time separator gets thicker compared to what it was initially set.

Comment: It doesn't draw lines and gives me this error - Assigning retained object to weak property; object will be released after assignment

Comment: Okay, I have done this with Storyboard. Thank you very much